# Mysql get employed past 3 year

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has `date_from` and `date_to` fields alongs other user related fields such as `first_name,last_name, etc...`.
`date_from` and `date_to` take employed start date, and end_date, what i want to take is to get all users, whose employed past 3 year.
I have checked like this:

```
IF(awe.date_to >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 YEAR),'Yes','No') AS 'Employed (Past 3 years)'
```

I'm confused is it right for that purpose or no?
`date_from` and `date_to` are `datetime`fields.

Answer (score 0):

I normally stored dates as unix time stamps this way you can then just do basic math.

```
date_from int(10)
date_to int(10)
```

//3 years in seconds is 94608000

//PHP code, but you can translate to whatever.

```
 if ($date_to - $date-from > 94608000){
    $employed = "+3 years";
 }else{
    $employed = "-3 years";
 }
```